# Scheme and Clojure don't have the atom type predicate - is this by design?

Tags: clojure, lisp, scheme, elisp, predicate

Common LISP and Emacs LISP have the atom type predicate. Scheme and Clojure don't have it. http://hyperpolyglot.wikidot.com/lisp

Is there a design reason for this - or is it just not an essential function to include in the API?

Comment: Besides general curiosity, is there a reason you'd find a use for it?  An object is either an atom or a compound object, and you'd usually be interested in what kind of compound object, right?

Comment: Some Schemes come with various little things like atom? predefined for your convenience.  For example, [Petite] Chez Scheme comes with most trivial functions you'd expect to exist.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Clojure, the atom predicate isn't so important because Clojure emphasizes various other types of (immutable) [data structures](http://clojure.org/data_structures) rather than focusing on cons cells / lists.

It could also cause confusion. How would you expect this function to behave when given a hashmap, a set or a vector for example? Or a Java object that represents some complex mutable data structure?

Also the name "atom" is used for something completely different - it's one of Clojure's core concurrency mechanisms [to manage shared, synchronous, independent state](http://clojure.org/atoms).

Answer (score 13):

Clojure has the `coll?` (collection?) function, which is (sort of) the inverse of `atom?`.

Answer (score 7):

In the book [The Little Schemer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262560992), `atom?` is defined as follows:

```
(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (pair? x))
       (not (null? x))))
```

Noting that `null` is not considered an atom, as other answers have suggested. In the mentioned book `atom?` is used heavily, in particular when writing procedures that deal with lists of lists.

Comment: scheme is really a weird language, it has null instead of nil, and null is not an atom. scheme must be the most weird dialect of lisp apart from javascript.

Comment: I think you must add '(not (procedure? x)' to this definition, unless you take a procedure is an atom.

Comment: @Alfgaar the predicate to check for nil in Common Lisp is also named "null"; that's not the name of the value itself. In Scheme the equivalent of nil is simply written as the empty list, `()`.  And I don't know why a procedure wouldn't be an atom; `(atom #'cons)`, for instance, is true in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 6):

In the entire IronScheme standard libraries which implement R6RS, I never needed such a function.

In summary:

- It is useless
- It is easy enough to write if you need it

Which pretty much follows Scheme's minimalistic approach.

Answer (score 2):

In Scheme anything that is not a `pair` is an `atom`. As Scheme already defines the predicate `pair?`, the `atom?` predicate is not needed, as it is so trivial to define:

```
(define (atom? s)
    (not (pair? s)))
```

Comment: Scheme does not know the difference between a pair and a list? Or has it changed the concept of pair? In Lisp there is no such a thing as a pair, only atoms, cons, and lists. As long as I know a pair consists of two things alone. So you can say that a list of two elements is a pair, but not a list of three or more. But taking a list of two elements as a pair is not conceptually good. It is better to tell one from the other.

Comment: @Alfgaar: That's not quite right.  A list is a recursive data structure: every list is either the empty list, or a pair where the second element, the cdr, is itself a list.  A list of 100 items is still a pair, comprising a chain of pairs.

Answer (score 1):

It's a trivial function:

```
(defun atom (x)
   (not (consp x)))
```

It is used in list processing, when the Lisp dialect uses conses to build lists. There are some 'Lisps' for which this is not the case or not central.

Answer (score 0):

Atom is either a symbol, a character, a number, or null.

```
(define (atom? a)
  (or (symbol? a)
      (char? a)
      (number? a)
      (null? a)))
```

I think those are all the atoms that exist, if you find more add to the `conditional expression`. For example, if you think a string is an atom, add (string? a), :-). The absence of a definition for atom, allows you to define it the way you want. After all, Scheme does not know what an atom is.

In Lisp `nil` is an atom, so I've made `null` an atom. `nil` is also a list by simplification `nil = (nil . nil)`, the same way the integral numbers are rational numbers by simplification, `2 = 2/1`, 2 is an integral number, 2/1 is a rational number, as both are equals by simplification of the rational one; one says the integral number 2 is also a rational number. But the list predicate is already defined in Scheme, nothing to worry about.

About the question. As long as I am concerned Scheme has predicates only for class types, atom is not a class type, atom is an abstraction that incorporates several class types. Maybe that is the reason. But pair is not a class type either, but it does not incorporate several class types, and yet some may consider pair as a class type.

Atom means that a certain thing is not a compound thing. One reason not to include such a predicate is when the language allows you to define atomic types, so the pletora of atoms can grow wider and wider, and such a predicate would make no sense. I don't know if Scheme allows for this. I can only say that Scheme predicates (the built-in ones) are all specific. You can ask, *is this an apple?*, *is this an orange?*; but you cannot ask *is this a fruit?*. :-). Well, you can, if you do it yourself. Despite what a said, Scheme has a general predicate `number?`, and number specific predicates, `integer?`, `rational?`, `real?`; notwithstanding, number can be thought of as a class type (the other predicates refer to sub-types of number), whereas atom is not (at least in Scheme).

**Note**:
*class types*: types that belong to a certain class of things. Example:

number, integer, real, rational, character, procedure, list, vector, string, etc.