# Why empty list is considered atom in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

As far I know, **atoms** are any of - numbers, booleans and strings in Scheme. But when I run the `atom?` function on empty list - `(atom? '())` - it returns true `#t` value.

What am I missing here? Does it have to with my Scheme language implementation i.e. Chicken Scheme?

Comment: Interestingly, the [definition of `atom?` used by the classic book The Little Schemer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9531513/9952196) is that an empty list is *not* an atom.

Comment: While [chicken's `atom?`](https://wiki.call-cc.org/man/5/Module%20\(chicken%20base\)#atom) "Returns `#t` if X is not a pair." which is in line with [Common Lisp's `atom`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_atom.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atom` comes from McCarthy's original 1960 lisp paper. It was a lisp with two types, symbols and pairs. The empty list is just a synonym for the symbol `nil` and it was self evaluating. `(atom ())` is the same as `(atom nil)` and both are true while `(atom (cons x y))` evaluates to the false value `nil`. Common Lisp is a direct descendant with more than two types, however it still works the same for code that only cares about pairs and symbols. As a design decsetion anything that is not pairs are atoms and thus:

```
(defun (atom x)
  (not (consp x)))
```

Scheme standards, as in the RNRS and R7RS being the latest, does not have `atom?` as a primitive. When that said it might be that some scheme implementation has it. While it would be least surprising to be implemented in the same way as Common Lisp, namely:

```
(define (atom? x)
  (not (pair? x)))
```

Paul Graham wrote an excellent article called [The roots of Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html) which I highly recommend.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mention of any atom concept in any Scheme standard that I can find.

In Common Lisp it is anything that's not a pair, and Scheme implementations that provide `atom?` most likely stick to that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if any Scheme standards define an `atom?` predicate.  However the traditional Lisp definition would be that an atom is any object which is not a cons.

Since a list is defined as being either the special empty list object which is not a cons, or a cons of any object and a list, it follows that the empty list object is an atom.

Comment: That rule also makes vectors and records atoms, which is much odder imo. But you get used to it.

Comment: @Shawn It's really just an archaeological curiosity I think: once the only non-atomic objects were conses (more-or-less: Lisp 1.5 has arrays but they are very second-class) so `atom` (as it was in those Lisps and still is in CL) was a good name.  But then people start using it to mean 'not a cons' and now you can't change it.  It's good that Scheme left it out.